# How to find difference in time from current date and a pre-determined date in python?

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

I am trying to find the difference in the number of days between current time and a given time in python.

For example, the time given is 2011-07-20 and the difference in the number of days at the point of posting this question is 41 days.

So my question is, how do I convert the given time into something that I can use to find the time difference in days. I am trying to make use of datetime.timedelta.now() - given time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Sure something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
d1 = datetime.strptime('2011-07-20', '%Y-%m-%d')

(d-d1).days
>>> 42 # number of total days beetween two given dates
```

Find more on strptime [using the following link](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#strftime-strptime-behavior).