# Time difference in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given two time points

```
t_1 = (hour_1, minute_1)
t_2 = (hour_2, minute_2)
```

How can I get the absolute time difference in minutes in Python 2.7, where 
I assume that `t_2` is later than `t_1`, so if:

```
t_2 = (0, 3) and t_1 = (23, 59)
```

the difference would be 4 Minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Comment: @CDspace unfortunately the OP does not appear to be using `datetime` objects.

Comment: with datetime  you need somehow the date which i don't have it tried with time objects but i can't compute the difference with t1 - t2 because time objects does not support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t_2 = (0, 3)
t_1 = (23, 59)

from datetime import timedelta

t1 = timedelta(hours=t_1[0],minutes=t_1[1])
t2 = timedelta(hours=t_2[0],minutes=t_2[1])
print((t2-t1).seconds/60)
4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.timedelta` objects (here `t1` is larger than `t2`):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t1 = (10, 0)
>>> t2 = (5, 5)
>>> d1 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60 * 60 * t1[0] + 60 * t1[1])
>>> d2 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60 * 60 * t2[0] + 60 * t2[1])
>>> d1 - d2
datetime.timedelta(0, 17995)
>>> (d1 - d2).total_seconds()
17995.0
```

Comment: If a student submitted this as their answer for what is clearly a trivial homework problem, I would immediately suspect plagiarism.

Comment: Did the OP want the difference in minutes?

Comment: @PaulRooney: I'm not sure, let's leave that as an exercise for the reader :)