# Comparing Time using datetime module in python

Tags: python, datetime, compare, difference

I have to find if a certain period of time in the format `datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)` is greater than 5 minutes. How can I do that? This is my code:

```
ttime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print "Current Time:- "+str(ttime)
a = raw_input("Press y and Enter")
if a=="y":
    print "OK!"
    ntime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    difference = ntime-ttime
    if difference> #I don't know what to put!:
        print "Difference is greater than 5 min"
    else:
        print "Difference is not greater than 5 min"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Comment: But this is not between two datetime objects!

Comment: @AlokNaushad, no, it is exactly two datetime objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difference = timedelta(minutes=5)`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> ttime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> ntime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> ntime - ttime > timedelta(minutes=5)
True
```

`timedelta` object initialized with 5 minutes:

```
>>> timedelta(minutes=5)
datetime.timedelta(0, 300)
```

To get more information read the docs about [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
ttime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print "Current Time:- "+str(ttime)
a = raw_input("Press y and Enter")
if a=="y":
    print "OK!"
    ntime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    if ttime < ntime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):
        print "Difference is greater than 5 min"
    else:
        print "Difference is not greater than 5 min"
```