# How to find time difference in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to find the time difference in minutes.

Below is the time format t1 and t2

```
 t1 =  01/24 14:50:0

 t2 = 1/24 14:52:01
```

Difference is two minutes

How to achieve this

I tried below code but not working:

```html
fmt = '%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
d1 = datetime.strptime('01/24 14:50:0', fmt)
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/24 14:52:01', fmt)
d1_ts = time.mktime(d1.timetuple())
d2_ts = time.mktime(d2.timetuple())
print (int(d1_ts-d2_ts) / 60)
```

Comment: What have you tried ? You might want to look at [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: @ IMCoins, Added what i tried. It is not working as expected

Comment: @preethytulpi `print (int(d2_ts-d1_ts) / 60)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in this way:

```
from datetime import datetime

# print("Hello Python")

t1 =  "31/12/2015 10:33:26"
t2 = "01/01/2016 10:33:37"

newdate1 = datetime.strptime(t1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
newdate2 = datetime.strptime(t2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

thedifference = newdate2 - newdate1

print(thedifference)
# Result: 1 day, 0:00:11
```

Make sure you import what you need on top

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    from datetime import datetime

    fmt = '%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = datetime.strptime('01/24 14:50:0', fmt)
    d2 = datetime.strptime('1/24 14:52:01', fmt)

    time_diff_in_secs = abs((d1-d2).total_seconds())

    print( time_diff_in_secs/60 ) #returns float

    #for int use, print( int(time_diff_in_secs/60) )
```