# What's wrong with this code using datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

CurrentDate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y') 
print(CurrentDate)

UserInput =  input("When is your birthday? (mm/dd/yyyy) ")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(UserInput, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
days = birthday - CurrentDate
print("your next birthday is in " + days )
```

It's giving me this error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and
>   'str'

I've tried to convert them with no result.

Comment: You're trying to subtract a `datetime.date` from a string. It sometimes helps to read the error messages ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python

Comment: `CurrentDate` is a string because you're calling `.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` on it for whatever reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is type casting from `date` to `str` and vice versa:

```
import datetime

CurrentDate = datetime.date.today()
print(CurrentDate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

UserInput =  input("When is your birthday? (mm/dd/yyyy) ")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(UserInput, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
days = birthday - CurrentDate
print("your next birthday is in " + str(days))
```

Answer (score 0):

As bernie mentioned, `CurrentDate` is a `string`

```
import datetime

CurrentDate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y') 
print(CurrentDate)

UserInput =  input("When is your birthday? (mm/dd/yyyy) ")
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(UserInput, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
current_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(CurrentDate, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
print(birthday)

days = (birthday - current_date
print("your next birthday is in " + str(days) )
```

Your algorithm might still need some work :)

```
02/01/2018
When is your birthday? (mm/dd/yyyy) 01/01/2018
2018-01-01
your next birthday is in -31 days, 0:00:00
```

Dividing the tweaked time difference by days will look cleaner:

```
days = (birthday - current_date)/datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print("your next birthday is in " + str(days) + " days")
```