# How do I use get the difference in time from 6:33 to 6:29 using 24 hour clock (6:33 is in a different day from 6:29)

Tags: python-2.7

How do I make it so that the place where I circled will calculate the difference in time for minutes?

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hello! Sure

    elif timeInHours == timeOutHours and  timeInMins > timeOutMins:
        durationStayHours = ((timeOutHours + DAILY_HOURS) - timeInHours) - 1
        durationStayMins =

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Arrow python library for this? It provided an API to calculate range between two time points: https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ranges-spans. This may work for your case.

Comment: We havent learned to do it with any libraries so we were supposed to just use raw math and if statements for this in class