# calculate the days between two times in python with presicion value

Tags: python, date

I have two times like `t1= "2018-04-28 10:32:32+00:00"` and `t2= "2018-04-29 20:32:32+00:00"`
Need to find the number of days between these two days. Actually in the above two days there is 36(means 1 and half day) hours difference is there so I need output as 1.5(which mean 1day and half day). How this is possible with python

Comment: Please show us your attempt on the problem.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python

Comment: This is two separate questions: [Converting a string time to a python datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) and [Finding the difference between two datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timedelta` in `datetime` module. I used `parse` for more date parsing.

```
In [2]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [3]: d1 = parse("2018-04-28 10:32:32+00:00")

In [4]: d2 = parse("2018-04-29 20:32:32+00:00")

In [5]: de = d2 - d1

In [6]: de.total_seconds()/ (60 * 60 * 24)
Out[6]: 1.4166666666666667
```