# how to convert FunctionName(t1: datetime, t2: datetime): to Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is an example located at 
[How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

It uses

```
def check_time_difference(t1: datetime, t2: datetime):
```

as in

```
def check_time_difference(t1: datetime, t2: datetime):
    t1_date = datetime(
        t1.year,
        t1.month,
        t1.day,
        t1.hour,
        t1.minute,
        t1.second)

    t2_date = datetime(
        t2.year,
        t2.month,
        t2.day,
        t2.hour,
        t2.minute,
        t2.second)

    t_elapsed = t1_date - t2_date

    return t_elapsed
```

I'm wondering, is there a way to convert that first line so that it works with Python 2?  In Python 2, I get an error that says

```
def check_time_difference(t1: datetime, t2: datetime):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It works fine in Python 3.

Comment: def check_time_difference(t1, t2):

Comment: Is your question how you can make it compatible with Python 2 without changing the code, or is your question how you can convert it to Python 2 code? If it's the former, you can't. If it's the latter, remove `: ...`

Comment: The parts like "t1: datetime" are called Type Hints which are new in python3.5.

Comment: `def check_time_difference(t1, t2): return t1-t2` .. the func is overly complicated... for python2 you simply remove the type hinting

Answer (score 1):

Type hints, [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), are new in Python 3.5.

The code you use will work under Python 2 if you just remove them:

```
def check_time_difference(t1, t2):
```

To make it truly compatible (as in: mypy will still be able to typecheck it), add a type hint comment:

```
def check_time_difference(t1, t2):
    # type: (datetime, datetime) -> timedelta
```

As far as I can see form [the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html) this syntax requires the return type (in this case: timedelta) to be annotated, too. In your Python 3 syntax example, it is ommitted, but it would look like:

```
def check_time_difference(t1: datetime, t2: datetime) -> timedelta:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the annotations; they don't have any impact on the functionality anyway.

```
def check_time_difference(t1, T2):
```

Note, as mentioned in the comments, the function is unnecessarily complicated - it should just return `t1 - t2`.