# Alternative to datetime.datetime.strftime() for cutting out unneeded units of time

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to compare two date times with an exact string output such as "3 hours, 2, minutes, 46 seconds". Now, say I have two datetime objects in UTC, I need them to be able to be an arbitrary amount but still cut off unneeded values. Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> date2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(123456789)
>>> date2 - date1
datetime.timedelta(-16362, 59566, 655021)
```

Now I could just use `datetime.datetime.strftime()` as a follow up but with the wide range of values I can encounter (1 second to months) I want to cut off the unneeded values and avoid "0 months, 0 weeks... etc." and "1 hour, 0 minutes, 0 seconds" without rounding (values are *always* positive). Is there an effient way to dynamically do this to only show relevent time values? I've looked through other questions similar to [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python) but none fully answer my question and I cannot figure it out on my own after many hours of tinkering.

Comment: Exactly which values are "relevant" and which are "unneeded"?  For example, if you just want resolution down to the day, you can use the `datetime.date()` method to convert to a `date` object.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this would need to be done with your own function. datetime objects have attributes for `months`, etc.  so you would need to implement these yourself.

Comment: @jwodder If I am given a date which is "4 hours, 0 minutes, and 10 seconds" difference to the current time, I don't want to return the "0 minutes". Same goes for not wanting to return "0 days" but adding that if there *are* days. Basically I want to return all values which do not have a value equal to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: ... do this to only show relevent time values?

The following implements your own `class Timedelta`:

```
class Timedelta(object):
    def __init__(self, td):
        self._td = td

        def _calc(s, f):
            _s = int(s % f)
            return _s, int(s / f)

        s, self.hours = _calc(self._td.seconds, (60 * 60))
        self.seconds, self.minutes = _calc(s, 60)

    def __str__(self):
        r = ""
        for v in [('Days', self._td.days), ('Hours', self.hours), ('Minutes', self.minutes), ('Seconds', self.seconds)]:
            if v[1] != 0:
                lingua = v[0]
                if v[1] == 1: lingua = v[0][:-1]
                r += "{} {} ".format(v[1], lingua)
        return  r

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({}) Days:{} Hours:{} Minutes:{} Seconds:{}"\
            .format((self._td.seconds), self._td.days, self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds)
```

> **Usage**:

```
date1 = dt.datetime(2018, 9, 17, hour=18, minute=23, second=0)
date2 = dt.datetime(2018, 9, 17, hour=22, minute=23, second=10)
dtt = date2 - date1
print("dtt:{}".format(dtt))

tdelta = Timedelta(date2 - date1)
print("Timedelta::\__repr\__: {}".format(tdelta.__repr__()))
print("Timedelta::\__str\__: {}".format(tdelta))
```

> **Output**:
>
> dtt:4:00:10
>   Timedelta::__repr__: (14410) Days:0 Hours:4 Minutes:0 Seconds:10
>   Timedelta:__str__: **4 Hours 10 Seconds**

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***