# Fill in the missing data using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataset, data-science, fillna

What's the best way to fill in the missing data using Pandas . I have a list of visitors where the exit time or the entry time is missing .

```
visitor entry            exit
A   16/02/2016 08:46    16/02/2016 09:01
A   16/02/2016 09:20    16/02/2016 17:24
A   17/02/2016 09:12    17/02/2016 09:42
A   17/02/2016 09:55    NaT
A   17/02/2016 12:42    17/02/2016 12:56
A   17/02/2016 13:02    17/02/2016 17:32
A   17/02/2016 17:44    17/02/2016 18:24
A   18/02/2016 07:59    18/02/2016 16:40
A   18/02/2016 16:53    NaT
A   NaT                 19/02/2016 09:11
A   19/02/2016 09:27    19/02/2016 11:26
A   19/02/2016 12:28    19/02/2016 17:12
A   20/02/2016 08:44    20/02/2016 08:58
A   20/02/2016 09:16    20/02/2016 17:21
```

Comment: What date do you want to complete? What is the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) + [`DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) 
to complete with the same time of entry / exit:

```
df[['entry','exit']]=df[['entry','exit']].ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
print(df)
   visitor               entry                exit
0        A 2016-02-16 08:46:00 2016-02-16 09:01:00
1        A 2016-02-16 09:20:00 2016-02-16 17:24:00
2        A 2016-02-17 09:12:00 2016-02-17 09:42:00
3        A 2016-02-17 09:55:00 2016-02-17 09:55:00
4        A 2016-02-17 12:42:00 2016-02-17 12:56:00
5        A 2016-02-17 13:02:00 2016-02-17 17:32:00
6        A 2016-02-17 17:44:00 2016-02-17 18:24:00
7        A 2016-02-18 07:59:00 2016-02-18 16:40:00
8        A 2016-02-18 16:53:00 2016-02-18 16:53:00
9        A 2016-02-19 09:11:00 2016-02-19 09:11:00
10       A 2016-02-19 09:27:00 2016-02-19 11:26:00
11       A 2016-02-19 12:28:00 2016-02-19 17:12:00
12       A 2016-02-20 08:44:00 2016-02-20 08:58:00
13       A 2016-02-20 09:16:00 2016-02-20 17:21:00
```

**EDIT**

[`DataFrame.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) + [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter to ros with NaT values in order to calculate the mean of the diff

```
#filtering valid data
df_valid=df[df.notna().all(axis=1)]
#Calculating diff
time_dif=df_valid[['entry','exit']].diff(axis=1).exit
print(time_dif)

0    00:15:00
1    08:04:00
2    00:30:00
4    00:14:00
5    04:30:00
6    00:40:00
7    08:41:00
10   01:59:00
11   04:44:00
12   00:14:00
13   08:05:00
Name: exit, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

```
#Calculatin mean        
time_dif_mean=time_dif.mean()
print('This is the mean of time in: ', time_dif_mean)

This is the mean of time in:  0 days 03:26:54.545454
```

---

**Filling mising value with the mean**

```
#roud to seconds( optional)
time_dif_mean_round_second=time_dif_mean.round('s')

df['entry'].fillna(df['exit']-time_dif_mean_round_second,inplace=True)
df['exit'].fillna(df['entry']+time_dif_mean_round_second,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

**Output:**

```
   visitor               entry                exit
0        A 2016-02-16 08:46:00 2016-02-16 09:01:00
1        A 2016-02-16 09:20:00 2016-02-16 17:24:00
2        A 2016-02-17 09:12:00 2016-02-17 09:42:00
3        A 2016-02-17 09:55:00 2016-02-17 13:21:55
4        A 2016-02-17 12:42:00 2016-02-17 12:56:00
5        A 2016-02-17 13:02:00 2016-02-17 17:32:00
6        A 2016-02-17 17:44:00 2016-02-17 18:24:00
7        A 2016-02-18 07:59:00 2016-02-18 16:40:00
8        A 2016-02-18 16:53:00 2016-02-18 20:19:55
9        A 2016-02-19 05:44:05 2016-02-19 09:11:00
10       A 2016-02-19 09:27:00 2016-02-19 11:26:00
11       A 2016-02-19 12:28:00 2016-02-19 17:12:00
12       A 2016-02-20 08:44:00 2016-02-20 08:58:00
13       A 2016-02-20 09:16:00 2016-02-20 17:21:00
```

Comment: Thanks that could a startup point to solve the issue . Any idea how to calculate the average time between a valid entry  and a  valid exit from two different  rows. In my example will be difference between exit index 0 and entry index 1 and so on for the all dataframe

Comment: Yes I have updated my solution for this, 
the average difference has a precision greater than the seconds you can choose to round it or not. Consider voting or accepting my answer if my answer solves your problem. Thank you:)

Comment: Thank you . I ended up using the mean per day per visitor however this wont be possible without your solution

Answer (score 0):

My best idea would require a few steps:

### 1. Create a new column that represents the total duration a visitor stayed for

```
visitor_log['duration'] = visitor_log['exit'] - visitor_log['entry']
```

You can reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python) on how to find the difference between 2 DateTimes.

### 2. Find the mean of the new column

```
mean_duration = visitor_log['duration'].mean()
```

### 3. Use that mean to fill in the missing data in either the entry or exit columns

```
visitor_log["entry"].fillna(value=visitor_log["exit"]-mean_duration,inplace=True)
visitor_log["exit"].fillna(value=visitor_log["entry"]+mean_duration,inplace=True)
```

Note that you will need to set [inplace=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to modify your existing DataFrame.