# How to sum hours each day between two dates in Python?

Tags: python

I have a start date and an end date, how do I calculate the hours of each day between two dates?

```
start date 2020-01-01 10:00
end date 2020-01-04 15:00
```

Example of sum of hours period between start date and end date:

```
2020-01-01 14 hours
2020-01-02 24 hours
2020-01-03 24 hours
2020-01-04 15 hours
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add what you have tried so far, so we can see where you get stuck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the times from strings to timestamp objects using the `datetime` module.  After that, you can step along each day and calculate the hours left in the day.  Finally add a check if the date is the same as the end date, use the hours in the end date for the time difference.

Reading in the datetimes from a string requires using the date-formatting syntax.  Basically, a percent sign followed by a letter is used to represent a standard portion of a datetime string.  I.e. `%H` is the hours in 24-hour format, `%Y` is the year, `%m` is month, and `%M` is minutes.  The dashes, spaces, slashes, colons and dots need to match what is in the string as well. For a complete list see this site: https://strftime.org/

```py
import datetime as dt

start_date = '2020-01-01 10:00'
end_date = '2020-01-04 15:00'

start = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
end = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

def hours_left(ts):
    return 24-(ts.hour + ts.minute / 60)

hours = []
day = start
for i in range(d.days + bool(d.seconds)):
    if day.date() != end.date():
        h = hours_left(day)
    else:
        h = end.hour + end.minute / 60
    hours.append((day.date(), h))
    day = day + dt.timedelta(hours=h)

hours
# returns:
[(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 14.0),
 (datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), 24.0),
 (datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), 24.0),
 (datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), 15.0)]
```

Here `hours` is a list of tuples containing the date and the hours.  If you want it as a list of strings you can pass it through a string formatter.

```py
hours_str = [f'{d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}  {h:.0f} hours' for d, h in hours]
hours_str
# returns
['2020-01-01  14 hours',
 '2020-01-02  24 hours',
 '2020-01-03  24 hours',
 '2020-01-04  15 hours']
```

Comment: I think this is missing a special case for when `start` and `end` are on the same day, but otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module: define your start and end date using `datetime` objects and simply substract one to the other.

You will end up with a `timedelta` object from which you can extract [the number of seconds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) (tip: there is 86400 seconds per day).