# How to find the time interval for the dataset with Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to find the time interval in Python.

So far, I did:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp1 = 737029.3541666665
earliest_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp1)
timestamp2 = 737036.3527777778
most_recent_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp2)
```

But I don't know how to go further.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by "time interval of this dataset"?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I edited my question.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC My issue is solved, and what I have tried stays in my question! And Before I write something here I always search on the internet. When I cannot find a solution I ask it. So what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Comment: I saw you removed the picture, is your data in a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @AMC Yes it is. I used the following function "pd.read_csv()" to load the data set.

Comment: @Vera How are you finding the most recent and oldest date?

Comment: @AMC With the min() and max() functions.

Comment: `min(df["col_name"])` ? There's always `df["col_name"].min()`, too.

Comment: @AMC I used the second one `df["col_name"].min()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two timestamps like (based in your example):

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp1 = 737029.3541666665
timestamp2 = 737036.3527777778
earliest_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp1)
most_recent_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp2)
```

The most simple way to get the time interval between these two date is like:

```
interval = most_recent_date - earliest_date
# this is a datetime.timedelta object but you can use str() and get some human readable string
str(interval)
# returns: '0:00:06.998611'
```

Comment: An additional question. The output 0:00:06.998611 is this a constant time interval?  Or not?

Comment: yes, it's the time difference between these two dates so, it should be constant if the dates are the same.