# How to plus datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have the program that generate datetime in several format like below.

```
1 day, 21:21:00.561566
11:19:26.056148
```

Maybe it have in month or year format, and i want to know are there any way to plus these all time that i get from the program.

Comment: Refer : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Can you add example of what you are inputting and what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- 1 day, 21:21:00.561566` is the string representation of a `datetime.timedelta` object. If you need to parse from string to timedelta, `pandas` has a suitable method. There are other third party parsers; I'm just using this one since `pandas` is quite common.

```
import pandas as pd
td = pd.to_timedelta('- 11:19:26.056148')
# Timedelta('-1 days +12:40:33.943852')
td.total_seconds()
# -40766.056148
```

If you need to find the sum of multiple timedelta values, you can `sum` up their `total_seconds` and convert them back to `timedelta`:

```
td_strings = ['- 1 day, 21:21:00.561566', '- 11:19:26.056148']
td_sum = pd.Timedelta(seconds=sum([pd.to_timedelta(s).total_seconds() for s in td_strings]))
td_sum
# Timedelta('-1 days +10:01:34.505418')
```

...or leverage some tools from the Python standard lib:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
td_sum = reduce(add, map(pd.to_timedelta, td_strings))
# Timedelta('-1 days +10:01:34.505418')
td_sum.total_seconds()
# -50305.494582
```

Comment: thank for response, actually there is no `-` in font of time, i just edited my code, but anyway i think this is whay i looking for :D

Comment: @Kaow: glad I could help. The sign doesn't matter actually, still a timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract date time like here to find how far apart these two times are:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345852/2415706

Adding two dates doesn't really make any sense though. Like, if you try to add Jan 1st of 2020 to Jan 1st of 1995, what are you expecting?

Comment: i have a time that i collect, may be 1 day, 2 day, 4 hours or 1 minute and what i want is to calculate the sum of these time so are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datatime.timedelta` class for this purpose.
You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).
You will need to parse your string and build a timedelta object.