# How to calculate duration in minutes between two datetimes values

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe. I want to calculate in a new column the difference between those two datetime value in minutes.

```
 Start date           End date  
    11/30/2011 23:58    12/01/2011 0:26
    11/30/2011 23:56    12/01/2011 0:01
    11/30/2011 23:18    11/30/2011 23:36
```

23:36

I tried and got this:
`df['trip_duration] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['End date'])`

```
0 -1 days +23:32:00
1 -1 days +23:55:00
2 -1 days +23:42:00
```

How do I get the difference in minutes like I mentioned above?

Comment: yo, this must help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the api is not super intuitive with some of the datetime stuff.  You can use this:

```
df['trip_duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['End date'] - df['Start date']).dt.seconds/60
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried it but i got issue: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'".

Comment: you have to cast it as datetime first - as you've done in your question

Comment: It's perfectly works. The main issue is in the formula: 'end value minus start value' instead of 'start minus end'

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your date columns are already in datetime format:

```
df['Start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start date'])
df['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End date'])
```

Then, you can get the time differences of the 2 columns by direct subtraction and then divide by [`pd.Timedelta('1 minute')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), like this:

```
df['trip_duration'] = (df['End date'] - df['Start date']) / pd.Timedelta('1 minute')
```

Resulting df:

```
           Start date            End date  trip_duration
0 2011-11-30 23:58:00 2011-12-01 00:26:00           28.0
1 2011-11-30 23:56:00 2011-12-01 00:01:00            5.0
2 2011-11-30 23:18:00 2011-11-30 23:36:00           18.0
```

Comment: @mike_duaud  Note that you don't need to call `pd.to_timedelta` since the difference between 2 datetime values is already in timedelta format.