# How to convert date/time string to an elapsed time in python

Tags: python, datetime

Using python, how does one convert a date/time retrieved from AWS to an elapsed time from present?  Depending on the actual interval, I would like to display it as years ago, days ago, hours ago, or minutes ago.  This "function" will be used in several scripts used to produce monthly audit data.

```
|-------------------------|---------------------|-------------------------|
|Group Name               |Group Id             |Create Date              |
|=========================================================================|
|AWS-Consultants          |AGPAYPADVGQQQBEUBC6SN|2020-06-08 15:28:20+00:00|
|-------------------------|---------------------|-------------------------|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a timedelta:

```py
from datetime import datetime,timezone
create = datetime.strptime('2020-06-08 15:28:20+00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc) - create)
```

Output:

```
417 days, 1:55:45.579676
```