How do I import this timestamp, and then get days since the timestamp?
I am receiving a timestamp as a string in this format 2024-09-27T04:58:04.894614Z
I've done a lot of playing and reading around using import datetime, converting to datetime objects
e.g. timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
But datetime seems extremely confusing to use.
I am current using
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta which cannot be changed.
How can I get the number of days since the imported timestamp please?

'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' That format string obviously won't work, because it doesn't have a T in the middle and a Z at the end, but your sample timestamp does.  The format string and the sample timestamp must match exactly.

This isn't some weird format, it's the ISO8601 format, the standard way of representing timestamps. You can parse it with datetime.fromisoformat, eg datetime.fromisoformat("2024-09-27T04:58:04.894614Z"). The standard specifies that T can be ommited for readability so datetime.fromisoformat("2024-09-27 04:58:04.894614Z") also works

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025345/26993270

Keep it simple,

Parse the string to a datetime object using strptime.
Use datetime.now() to get the current time.
Subtract the parsed datetime from the current time and extract the days from the result.


from datetime import datetime

timestamp = "2024-09-21T04:58:04.894614Z"
timestamp_dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
now = datetime.now()
difference = now - timestamp_dt
days_since = difference.days

You can also use fromisoformat, as suggested by Mark Tolonen:
timestamp_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp.rstrip("Z"))

Note that the date format is wrong also, the correct one should be:
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ


Full example

Thank you! This is exactly what I needed :)

Simpler to use .fromisoformat()

You are right @MarkTolonen I include it in my answer

You don't have to strip the 'Z'.  It makes a time zone-aware datetime using UTC.
